# Async/ Await nesting issues ? Block of code not executing

Tags: node.js, async-await, logic, puppeteer

I have a block of code that doesnt seem to be executing.
I'm using Node.Js 8.9 on Ubuntu 16.04

```
const puppet =  require("puppeteer");
const fs = require("fs");

let oldIP = "";
( async () =>{
const browser = await puppet.launch({headless:false});
const Page = await browser.newPage();

try {
await Page.goto("http://192.168.100.1");
await Page.waitFor(1000);

await Page.click("#txt_Username");
await Page.keyboard.type(username);
await(console.log("Entered Username"));

await Page.focus("#txt_Password");
await Page.keyboard.type(passwd);
await(console.log("Entered Password"));

await Page.click("#button");
await(console.log("Authenticating"));
await Page.waitForNavigation("load");
await Page.goto("http://192.168.100.1/html/bbsp/waninfo/waninfo.asp");



let ip = await Page.evaluate(async ()=>{
let address = await document.querySelector("#record_0>td:nth-child(3)").innerText;
await console.log(address);
return address;
});

await console.log("Public(NEW) IP Address is: "+ ip);    

fs.readFileSync("Currentaddress.txt", "utf8", async (err,data)=>{
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Test:"+oldIP);

    //Why is this code not getting executed?
    if(data){
        oldIP = data.trim();
        await console.log("Old IP is :"+oldIP);
    }


});

await (async ()=>{
    if (ip!==oldIP){
        fs.writeFileSync("Currentaddress.txt", ip, "utf8", async (err,data)=>{
            if(err) console.log(err);   
        });

    await console.log("Old IP 2 is :"+oldIP);   
    await console.log("new Ip written  "+ip);
    await process.exit(1);
    }
    //If they're the same
    await (async ()=>{
    await console.log("No changes Noted");
    await process.exit(1);
    })();

})();

}
//end of try block

catch(error){
    console.log(error);
}
})();

let username = "root";
let passwd = "process.env.PASSWD";
```

That block of code under the comment `//why is this code not getting executed?` is not firing. 
I added the console.log() to check and it doesn't fire. The code runs without any syntax errors.

I'm trying to create a script to check my router's public IP address.
I've succeeded in getting the IP and writing it to the txt file.

However, reading the file doesnt seem to work.

Here's my output,

```
Entered Username
Entered Password
Authenticating
Public(NEW) IP Address is: xx.xx.xxx.xx
Old IP 2 is :
new Ip written  xx.xx.xxx.xx
```

I've obfuscated the IP for security purposes but it does return a valid IP address.

`Old IP 2 is :` however remains blank.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you using `await` with synchronous operations such as `await console.log(...)`.  That makes no sense at all.  It makes it appear that you don't understand what `await` actually does because using it on a synchronous operation that does not return a promise does nothing - wasted and misleading code.

Comment: Also, where does `document` get defined in your code so that you can do `document.querySelectorAll()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) is synchronous, so try this:

```
try {
  var data = fs.readFileSync("Currentaddress.txt"), {encoding: "utf8"});
  if(data){
    var oldIP = data.trim();
    console.log("Old IP is :"+oldIP);
  }
} catch (error) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

readFileSync is synchronous. If you want async function you should use fs.readFile https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_path_options_callback

Actually it should be done like this:

```
fs.readFile("Currentaddress.txt", "utf8", (err,data)=>{
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log("Test:"+oldIP);

    //Why is this code not getting executed?
    if(data){
        oldIP = data.trim();
        console.log("Old IP is :"+oldIP);
    }


});
```

If you want to await fs.readFile you should promisify it first.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making **readFileSync** convert readFile to promise and call using await. because if you use readFileSync it blocks the thread and stops other processes until readFileSync done.

Convert readFile callback to promise using **util.promisify**.

```
const fs = require("fs");
const util = require('util');
const readFile = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
```

Using await

```
let data = await readFile('Currentaddress.txt', 'utf8');
if (data) {
    oldIP = data.trim();
    await console.log("Old IP is :" + oldIP);
}
```